# Python 3.5 + Django + PostgreSQL no Windows

Tags: postgresql, django, python-3.x

Atualmente estou iniciando um projeto de sistema web usando Python 3.5 e a framework Django 1.9.1, tendo como intuito integra-los com um banco de dados [PostgreSQL 9.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/install/#s-get-your-database-running), todos instalados em uma máquina com OS Windows 10 x64.

A instalação do Python e do Django ocorreu bem usando o "pip", porém não consegui achar o adaptador para PostgreSQL do Django referente ao Python 3.5 . Oficialmente é mantido um adaptador chamado [win-psycopg](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/) (que por sua ver só dá suporte até a versão Python 3.4), derivado do [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/).

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma outra opção de driver de conexão DB do Django no Windows para PostgreSQL? ou se é possível forçar esse adaptador da versão 3.4 para a versão 3.5?

Comment: As bibliotecas do postgres estão instaladas no python e o SGBD do postgres está rodando na maquina ou em algum servidor?

Comment: está tudo rodando local na minha máquina

Comment: já cogitou a ideia de usar ctypes e hibernate? creio que não seja o meio mais viável, mas pode resolver seu problema

Answer (score 1):

Adaptadores que são referentes a versão 3 serão, muito raramente, incompatíveis com versões mais atuais.

Mas caso você esteja rodando o Python 2.X você deve procurar um para ele! Desde já afirmo que este adaptador da versão 3.4 deve funcionar sim com a versão 3.5, já que não houve nenhum update ou algo do gênero.

Caso você queira mexer com NoSQL, eu recomendo a você usar o SQLite ou a própria função open() do Python, assim você vai ter uma maior eficiência e menos necessidade de poder de processamento.

Em um projeto que desenvolvi de um encurtador de urls(http://wp-a.co) ele é inteiramente feito em flask e sqlite, por isso recomendo a utilização! O código está disponível no github!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar forçar o adaptador, mas é capaz que tenham alguns bugs de diferenças de versão(que devem ser mínimos, mas existem) ou ainda testar outro tipo de banco de dados como o sqlite em conjunto com um outro web framework como o Flask ou o Bottle!

Se você usar estes dois que eu indiquei(flask e sqlite ou bottle e sqlite) seu import deve ficar assim:

```
import sqlite
from flask import *
```